# Using Auth0 for Google Authentication in Ionic2 running in Browser Offline Access

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2, google-authentication, auth0

I am trying to use Auth0 for my Ionic2 test app. I am trying to get Google login working in 'ionic serve' or 'ionic run browser'. This is my Auth0 setup

```
  auth0 = new Auth0({clientID: 'yyy', domain: 'xxx.auth0.com' });
  lock = new Auth0Lock('yyy', 'xxx.auth0.com', {
    auth: {
      redirect: false,
      params: {
          scope: 'openid',
        //scope: 'openid offline_access', // DOES NOT WORK
        device:'Mobile device'
      }
    }
  });
```

requesting offline_access is causing the authentication to fail with error

```
{
error: "invalid_request", 
errorDescription: "device parameter must be specified", 
state: "aaa-bbb"
}
```

why is this failing despite the fact I provide a deviceName?

Comment: does this help maybe you missed something? http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-and-auth0/

Comment: @suraj I went through guides from Auth0, but this seems to be exact same guide. Can't see anything missing. I realise why the 'deviceName' is required and why it does not make sense for browser mode, because it is not a device. But can I somehow provide it myself like the tutorial suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer in [this discussion](https://auth0.com/forum/t/authorize-and-the-device-parameter/161/2).

Setting 'device name' in browser to get offline access is intentionally not provided.

> We do not recommend using this flow for web applications (running in the browser), since the browser is not a device. To prevent expiration of session in the context of a web app, is better to increase the lifetime of the JWT and then automatically refresh the token every time the user goes to the application.

I suggest trying in a device.
`ionic run <platform> --device` should work.

Comment: Had seen that, but because it says 'not recommend' I had assumed it should still work. But I give up!

Comment: Well . if it had worked it would probably have been treated as a bug by 'Auth0' :)